# Laravel Unable to connect my SFTP server with privatekey.pem / privatekey.ppk

Tags: php, laravel, sftp, flysystem

im trying to connect my **SFTP Server** with **privatekey.pem / privatekey.ppk**
But still getting same error which is **"Could not login with username : XXXXX , host : XX.XX.XX.XX"**
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/icMPx.png

Initially, i have **privatekey.ppk** then i convert to **privatekey.pem** using **puttygen** because i thought that Laravel cant use file **.ppk** . But the result still same.

btw , I can access through **WinSCP** with my **privatekey.ppk** and **Terminal** with my **privatekey.pem** . But unfortunately Laravel , i cannot get through.

Some info im using :

- Laravel 8
- Php 7
- league/flysystem-sftp: 1.1
- phpseclib/phpseclib: 2.0

I also have try **phpseclib** connection but still same

```
use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;
use phpseclib\Net\SFTP;

    $key = new RSA;
    $key->loadKey(file_get_contents('C:/key/privatekey.pem'));
    
    $sftp = new SFTP('XX.XX.XX.XX');
    
    if (!$sftp->login('XXXXX', $key)) {
        dd($sftp->getLog());
    }
```

my **config\filesystems.php**

```
        'sftp' => [
        'driver' => 'sftp',
        'host' => 'XX.XX.XX.XX',
        'username' => 'XXXX',
        'privateKey' => file_get_contents('C:/key/privatekey.pem'),
        'root' => '/upload'
    ]
```

my **myprivatekey.pem**

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAAAMwAAAAtzc2gtZW
QyNTUxOQAAACAiSbn2URP33h/UjsByVXQA1H/sb8eNTf4PjPFlRdYp4gAAAJj7Xoxl+16M
ZQAAAAtzc2gtZWQyNTUxOQAAACAiSbn2URP33h/UjsByVXQA1H/sb8eNTf4PjPFlRdYp4g
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Hope somebody can give me some idea what's going on. thank you

Comment: *"But still same"* means exactly what? I'm sure you get much more specific error/message form phpseeclib, then the vague Laravel message.

Comment: i have try $sftp->getErrors()  and $sftp->getSFTPErrors() but both return empty array ;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe problem is that privateKey in config should be path to file, not content.

I'm using SFTP in my app:

I followed this docs: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#sftp-driver-configuration

.env

```
 SFTP_HOST=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
 SFTP_USERNAME=foo
 SFTP_PASSWORD=bar
 SFTP_PORT=22
 SFTP_KEY=/private/key/file/id_rsa
 SFTP_PATH=/folder/on/remote/server
```

filesystems.php

```
'remote_sftp' => [
        'driver' => 'sftp',
        'host' => env('SFTP_HOST'),
        'username' => env('SFTP_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('SFTP_PASSWORD'),
        'port' => (int)env('SFTP_PORT', 22),
        'privateKey' => env('SFTP_KEY'),
        'passphrase' => '',
        'path' => env('SFTP_PATH'),
    ],
```

and i get files on that remote disk:

```
$sftpStorage = Storage::disk('remote_sftp');
$remoteFiles = $sftpStorage->allFiles(config('filesystems.disks.remote_sftp.path'));
```

I hope that this can help.